# How can I get the average of the values in three columns?

Tags: mysql

I have this table named rating:

```
id | helpful | necesary | lenght
1  |    3    |    1     |   5
1  |    4    |    3     |   2
2  |    5    |    3     |   5
3  |    3    |    3     |   5
1  |    1    |    2     |   3
3  |    2    |    3     |   2
```

This table stores the rating a user gives to anarticle from 1 to 5....How can I query the top 5 id that has the highest rating having averaged the 3 colums helpful, necesary, length?

AVG gives me the average for a column and LIMIT well gives me the top 5, but I can't get a start on how to average three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to do this:

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id, (helpful + necesary + legnth) / 3 average
        FROM rating ORDER BY average DESC
) t
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to add the values from the columns and divide them by the number of columns.

```
SELECT (helpful + necesary + length) / 3 AS "avg" FROM rating ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the values manually, sort by that sum, and then divide the sum by the number of columns to get the average:

```
select id, helpful, necesary, lenght,
  ((helpful + necesary + lenght) / 3) as avg
from rating
order by (helpful + necesary + lenght) desc
limit 5
```